# correct using of " in this variavle

Tags: javascript, php, variables, button

I cant figure out how i have to put the strings in this variable to let it work.

```
$button_uploader = '<button class="uploader_button" onclick="location.href='uploader.php' type="button">Upload hier je antwoorden</button>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you realy want to do that, use antislash character. Ex : \'upload.php\'

But I suggest to you to not insert your javascript here and create separed file.

Look at something like that :

php/html, add id attribute to your button :

```
$button_uploader = '<button id="my_uploader_button" class="uploader_button" type="button">Upload hier je antwoorden</button>';
```

js :

```
var my_uploader_button = document.getElementById('my_uploader_button');

my_uploader_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
window.location.href='uploader.php';
});
```

Comment: doesn't work... file has been found: view-source:https://www.jouwantwoorden.nl/core/assets/js/button.js

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var file = "uploader.php";
$button_uploader = '<button class="uploader_button" onclick="location.href='+file+'" type="button">Upload hier je antwoorden</button>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You must concatenate Strings, try it:

```
 $button_uploader = '<button class="uploader_button" onclick="location.href='+'uploader.php'+'" type="button">Upload hier je antwoorden</button>';
```

Comment: my button becomes a 0

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by:

```
$button_uploader='<button class="uploader_button" onclick="location.href=\'/uploader.php\'" type="button">Upload hier je antwoorden</button>';
```

As a note,
have a look at the slash `/` before the `uploader.php`
It will take you to: 
http://example.com/uploader.php

without slash the string is appended to your url, so you would go to:
http://example.com/what/ever/page/you/have/uploader.php

Backslash `\` inside a string `"this is a string with some \"quotes\" inside"`helps you to include the quote you use **inside** the string **text**.